# Photoshop Brush Problems

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I started using Photoshop to create digital drawings. Whenever I try to draw with the brush, it comes out blurry and pixelated. When I zoom in, I can see the pixels that made up the brush stroke. I tried using different brushes (Photoshop default brushes and user created) but they all have a blurry look. I put the hardness to 100% but it still looks blurry. I tried using different canvas sizes, but that doesn't fix the problem. How do I fix this to create smooth brush strokes (without pen tool)?

[image]

Example of a blurry/pixelated brush stroke whenever the brush is used

[image]

(Zoomed in) Pixels that make up the brush stroke

[image]

Brush with spacing 1% and resolution at 200 (still pixelated)

Comment: You really *never* want a brush spacing at 1%. Your'e repeating pixels too often that way. But anyway... issues with brush smoothness are **often** traced to  issues with *hardware*. Especially if this is a new system or fresh install of Photoshop. Note that "zoomed in" is *always* gong to make pixel edges far more visible.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between raster images and vector images?  There is *no such thing* as a smooth curve in a raster image that won’t appear pixelated when you zoom in.  For that you need vector artwork; try using Inkscape (free) or Adobe Illustrator if you have it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Don't zoom in on raster images more than 100%. You will see pixels if you do that.  There is nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

what is your image size ?  If the resolution is set to 72 it will display pixelated, depending on what monitor you have too.

For 2019 I recommend setting the image resolution to 144 which is HD quality.

Also in your **Brush Settings** you might have the brush set on higher spacing. You could lower it down and have a way smoother outcome

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you said (I put the resolution at 144 and then to 200; fixed the spacing to 1%) but the brush is still pixelated (image added to the original post).

Comment: Have you tried resetting or Restoring Default brushes, maybe the brush you're using is traced from a pixelated version.

Comment: The brush is one of the default brushes in Photoshop.

Comment: Resolution (dpi) doesn't mean anything for digital files. What's your document size in pixels (width/height)?

Answer (score 1):

**The Issue might be shape Dynamics** (Not Sure)

maybe you have shape dynamics on; so make it off cuz `jitter` can make your brush faded;

[image]